# How to set vscode/gitlens as the default editor for git in wsl

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gitlens

### Problem

When I start an interactive rebase from a windows cmd, the interactive gitlens rebase window pops up on vscode. When I do the same from wsl, the plain txt rebase file shows up on vscode.
Is there a way to make it so that when I rebase from the wsl, the gitlens rebase shows up?

### Steps to reproduce

I Installed wsl with:

```bash
wsl --install
```

Then I selected the default:

```bash
wsl --setdefault Ubuntu
```

I then installed git again on the wsl with:

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install git
```

I then tried to set vscode as the default editor:

```bash
$ git config --global core.editor "/mnt/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code --wait"
```

I got the vscode path by running:

```bash
$ Which code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend following a process similar to [this article](https://cse232-msu.github.io/CSE232/vscode_setup/windows.html#preparing-vscode-for-c) which involve:

- installing the "remote development" extension
- Close out of the VSCode instance you were just using to install the Remote Development extension, and bring up your Linux terminal (WSL).
- Run the command: `cd; code .` (space dot)
- Search for GitLens in the extensions, and click "`Install in WSL: Ubuntu-20.04`"

After installing GitLens on WSL, you should see the same interactive rebase window as when you use Git from CMD.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I had to reinstall the extensions on the wsl environment.